# Android make call with popup select sim to outgoing call

Tags: android, kotlin

We build a custom dialer application but in dual sim phone I'm wanting to show a popup select sim slot to make call. I'm try use this case `defaultSubId == SubscriptionManager.INVALID_SUBSCRIPTION_ID` return true when **Default Sim** is unset in settings but in Samsung A750 **return 2** even if setup always ask.

Is there any other way to check default sim settings?

My Code

```
 val list: List<PhoneAccountHandle> = telecomManager.callCapablePhoneAccounts
        if (list.count() == 1) {
            val uri: Uri = Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null)
            telecomManager.placeCall(uri, extras)
            return;
        }

        val subMgr =
            getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE) as SubscriptionManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            val defaultSubId =
                SubscriptionManager.getDefaultVoiceSubscriptionId();


            Log.d(tag, "defaultSubId $defaultSubId")

            if (defaultSubId == SubscriptionManager.INVALID_SUBSCRIPTION_ID) {
                requestSelectSim(list, telecomManager, phone);
                return;
            }

            val defaultSubInfo =
                subMgr.getActiveSubscriptionInfo(defaultSubId)

            makeCallBySimInfo(telecomManager, list[defaultSubInfo.simSlotIndex], phone)
        } else {
            // android <7.0
        }
    }

    private fun makeCallBySimInfo(
        telecomManager: TelecomManager,
        info: PhoneAccountHandle,
        phone: String
    ) {
        val uri: Uri = Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null)
        val extras = Bundle()
        extras.putParcelable(
            TelecomManager.EXTRA_PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE,
            info
        )
        telecomManager.placeCall(uri, extras)
    }

  @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private fun requestSelectSim(
        list: List<PhoneAccountHandle>,
        telecomManager: TelecomManager,
        phone: String
    ) {
        val alert = ViewDialog()
        alert.showDialog(activity, callbackSim1 = {
            //To call from SIM 1
            makeCallBySimInfo(telecomManager, list[0], phone)
        }, callbackSim2 = {
            //To call from SIM 2
            makeCallBySimInfo(telecomManager, list[1], phone)
        })
    }
```